# How to correctly add "checked" to a radio button group in a loop?

Tags: angular

Usually `checked` just add at the end of input

```
<input type="radio" name="item" value="value1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="item" value="value2">
```

But now I am using *ngFor. I want to select the first one.

I try to do this, but it does not work, because `checked` is not a class.

```
<div *ngFor="#item of collection; #i = index"">
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="{{item}}" [ngClass]="{'checked':i === 0}">
    <label>{{item}}</label>
</div>
```

So how can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="item" value="{{item}}" [attr.checked]="i === 0 ? '' : null">
```

Comment: it is weird, it shows this in dev tool: `<input name="item" type="radio" value="value1" checked="true">
<input name="item" type="radio" value="value2" checked="false">`, but the page actually select the last one

Comment: It should be `[attr.checked]="i === 0 ? true : null"` boolean attributes are only removed on `null` not on `false`.

Comment: @HongboMiao yea, this won't work since `checked` is evaluated by attribute name, not by attribute value...

Comment: yeah, @GünterZöchbauer is correct, I just made a test and found `checked="true"` and `checked="false"` actually all same like `checked`

Comment: @Sasxa can u update the answer, so I can accept, thanks