# How to get first element of md-radio-button checked within *ngFor (angular2)

Tags: html, angular, radiobuttonlist, ngfor

Please I have this code snippet:

```
<md-radio-group>
      <span *ngFor="let size of item.sizes; let i = index;">
        <md-radio-button [value]="size.id" [attr.checked]="i === 0 ? '' : null">
          <span class="inline inset text-capitalize" >{{size.name}} </span>
        </md-radio-button>
      </span>
    </md-radio-group>
```

I want that first `md-radio-button` will be **checked by default**, that's why I've added `[attr.checked]="i === 0 ? '' : null"` following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444629/how-to-correctly-add-checked-to-a-radio-button-group-in-a-loop) but nothing happened. Any ideas how to achieve that please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `md-radio-button` being a custom component, you cannot check it with an attribute like you would do with an `<input type="radio">`.

But maybe you could set a default value on your `ngModel` or `formControl`...?

```html
<md-radio-group [(ngModel)]="foo">
  <span *ngFor="let size of item.sizes; let i = index;">
    <md-radio-button [value]="size.id" [attr.checked]="i === 0 ? '' : null">
      <span class="inline inset text-capitalize" >{{size.name}} </span>
    </md-radio-button>
  </span>
</md-radio-group>
```

```js
ngOnInit(){
  this.foo=item.sizes[0].id;
}
```

Comment: Yes :D , Thanks I'll try it now !

Comment: Thank you very much , you rocks !